# Java and lookbehind in regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to find a regex for the following:

All worlds matching `@WORD@` exactly where `WORD` could be any word at all but are only after an `=` .
I made the following:
`(?<==)#.*?#)` which works but only for patterns like `=@SOMEWORD@` or `@ANOTHERWORD@` but **not** for `=  @WORD@`.
I am also interested in **not** being followed by `=` but could not figure out that.
Anyway using something like: `(?<=\\s*=\\s*)#.*?#)` but it does not work.
Any ideas?

Note: Strange but from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543746/java-regex-error-look-behind-group-does-not-have-an-obvious-maximum-length) it says that variable length lookbehind is **not** supported in Java but this does not give me an exception

Answer (score 1):

If you are using look-behind, I'm assuming you are using `Pattern` and `Matcher` directly, to catch the words clean (`"@WORD@"` instead of `"= @WORD@"`).

If that is indeed the case, all you need to do is add an optional white-space within the look-behind:

`(?<==\\s?)@.*?@`

---

Here is a test-code, returning `"@WORD@"`:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<==\\s?)@.*?@").matcher("= @WORD@");
m.find();
System.out.println(m.group());
```

Answer (score 0):

This pattern matches an equals, followed by an optional space and a word encased in @ symbols:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("= ?@(.*)@");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("=@WORD@");
if (matcher.matches()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}

// Prints: "WORD"
```

Can't see a need for a lookbehind, unless I've misunderstood the task you wish to accomplish. However, the following should work:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<== ?)@(.*)@");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("= @WORD@");
if (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}

// Prints: "WORD"
```

The negative pattern is then accomplished as follows:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!= ?)@(.*)@");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("=@WORD@");
System.out.println(matcher.find());

// Prints: "false"
```