# How to replace the text in two substrings of a string?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a requirement where I get a string in which I have to replace the value between

```
< p811:Credential> and   < /p811:Credential>
```

In this case `AAAAA`/`BBBBBB`)

Only the Credential text will be constant all the time the prefix will need not be the same

Example strings

1.`abc < p811:Credential>AAAAA/BBBBBB< /p811:Credential>xyz`
2.`gsd< K999:Credential>EEEEE/XXXXX< / K999:Credential>tre`

How can we do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace a substring of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702357/how-to-replace-a-substring-of-a-string)

Comment: What is the before and after?

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: < p811:Credential> and   < /p811:Credential> will be the only content in that line right?

Comment: @Fathah Rehman P No, Its the part of the string and the content in the string varries excpet the Credential. 
Below 2 strings 2 possible strings i can get
1.abc < p811:Credential>AAAAA/BBBBBB< /p811:Credential>xyz
2.gsd< K999:Credential>EEEEE/XXXXX< / K999:Credential>tre

Answer (score 2):

For solving your specific problem , you can give this code:

```
line=" gsd< K999:Credential>EEEEE/XXXXX< / K999:Credential>tre";
String REGEX="(?<=Credential\\W?>)(\\w|\\d|/)*(?=<\\W?/\\W?(\\w|\\d)+:Credential\\W?>)";

line = line.replaceAll(REGEX, word_to_replace);
System.out.println(line);
```

Comment: I am sorry not to mention this,p811 will need not to be same always  i.e it can be like this aswell
gsd< K999:Credential>EEEEE/XXXXX< / K999:Credential>tre

Comment: Can you give sample acceptable inputs and unacceptable inputs ?

Comment: String replacement="< p811:Credential>"+replaceWord+"< /p811:Credential>";
how do you replace this  if we have string like this
gsd< K999:Credential>EEEEE/XXXXX< / K999:Credential>tre

Comment: the trouble with this solution is it will match `<abc:Credential>foo</xyz:Credential>`

Comment: @Bohemian : I given 2nd solution to solve his specific problem.  NO the 2nd solution will not match <abc:Credential>foo</xyz:Credential> for sure. Why I given specific code because of  the error  :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706793/regex-java-look-behind-group-does-not-have-an-obvious-maximum-length-near

Comment: @Bohemian : I edited my answer . Thank you for you comment. Now it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
String search = "abc < p811:Credential>AAAAA/BBBBBB< /p811:Credential>xyz";

String regex = "(^.*?< ?[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}:Credential>)(.*?)(< ?/ ?[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}:Credential>.*?$)";
String replacement = "$1Replacement Text$3";

String result = search.replaceAll(regex, replacement);
```

I put 3 capture groups in the regex:

- `.........< XXXX:Credential>`
- >`XXXX/XXXXX`<
- `< / XXXX:Credential>.........`

Then simply put an easy replacement text, which uses backreferences `$1` and `$3` to preserve the characters to the left and right of your desired match.