# RegEx to match a string between a set of words

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to match a group of words between two words in a String. I will be using Java RegEx.

**Input Text**

```
The clever fox JUMPED OVER the big dog and ran away.
```

**Expected Output**

```
the big
```

**RegEx Used**

```
(?<=(fox\s[A-Z0-9]*))(?s)(.*?)(?=\sdog)
```

**I get below output which gives me all words between fox and dog**

```
JUMPED OVER the big
```

The word **"fox"** will be followed by **one or more all upper case words** always. I need to match all the words following these two words till I get **"dog"**.

Also I need to get the desired output in Capture Group 0. I can not use different capture groups. This is a limitation in my application.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "a group of words between two words". What are these two words?

Comment: @Tichodromamuraria in the example string, I need all words between the words "fox JUMPED OVER" and "dog". Please pardon my english, these are more than 2 words.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid java [doesn't support variable length look behind assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543746/java-regex-error-look-behind-group-does-not-have-an-obvious-maximum-length).

In addition [capture group 0 is the full text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865377/java-regex-capture-group) which due to variable length lookbehinds not being allowed (as explained before) is impossible unless you know there is always going to be a certain length of uppercase words.

To do this with capture group 1 try:

```
(?<=fox)(?:\s[A-Z0-9]*)*\s?(.*?)(?=\sdog)
```

EDIT: Fixed typo in regex

EDIT 2: clarified fulltext problem.

EDIT 3: Depending on how stupid java is with "non-obvious maximum length of lookbehind group" this might work: `(?<=fox(?:\s[A-Z0-9]{5,7}){1,2})(.*?)(?=\sdog)` but I need to ask, what makes you so sure that you need this to be capture group 0? I somewhat doubt that's the case, even if it does you can just take the output and then run it again against `.*` to get a regex of capture group 0, there's no way you really need this as a requirement.

Comment: Yes, I was able to get the desired text in capture group 1. But I need it as full text i.e., group 0. Also tried to use your regex, it is not giving me the desired text in capture group 1. Not sure if I am missing anything here. Not very knowledgeable in RegExes. Thanks for warning about the variable length look behind.

Comment: It is impossible to get the fulltext to be in capture group 0 as I said, due to the variable length lookbehind not being allowed, sorry I had a typo in the regex, fixed now.

Comment: I think I can have the minimum and maximum characters that the upper case word will have. Can that help. Lets say for example my upper case word will have minimum 5 and max 7 characters

Comment: and is there a set number of words there can be?

Comment: Tried with your regex in EDIT3. It gives me result as **D OVER the big**

Comment: when I try it I get an error about `Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near` did you read the rest of it? there's no way that there is a strong requirement for you to have a capture group of 0

Comment: Are you sure it's java regexes? because you should be getting the error, if you don't get an error, try: `(?<=fox(?:\s[A-Z0-9]*)*\s?)(.*?)(?=\sdog)` as this will work if you're allowed variable spaced lookbehinds.

Comment: Yes, its Java RegEx. Am using one tool called Expresso for testing the RegExes. It gave no error for the regex in EDIT3. As for not using capture 1, I know this could be easily achieved in Java code. But my application is not in Java. I need to feed this regex into other application which uses java.

Comment: The EDIT3 regex works as per my need if I change the word repetitions to exact 2. But that may not be the case, I can have 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^.*fox[A-Z0-9\s]*(.*)dog.*$
```

You can pass `fox` and `dog` by parameter in your function to use in other cases.

Comment: This gives me the matched words in group 1. Is there a way I can get it in group 0. Many thanks for your answer

Comment: You could use the group-ignore syntax by changing `(.*)` to `(?=.*)`. This lets the matcher ignore the group.

Comment: @maxdev after doing the change that you told I dont get any match. The RegEx looked like this 

    ^.*fox[A-Z0-9\s]*(?=.*)dog.*$

Comment: @immzi I only get 1 match, insn´t it?? group 0="the big". What value  you get in group 0??

Comment: @Andynedine group 1 is "the big" group 0 is "The clever fox JUMPED OVER the big dog and ran away."

Comment: you're right. Well @immzi ... I don't know how you can ignore that macht 0. Can you show all your code to help you?? Perhaps we can find some alternate solution

Comment: @Andynedine There is no java code for this. I have to give this RegEx in a tool which does further processing. So I need the RegEx itself to give me the matching words in group 0

Comment: @immzi I downloaded Expresso app from http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm, and y I used the regex. I think if you fing a match, always it'll show you your initial string, but y you use "REPLACE BUTTON", you'll get "THE BIG" really.... You used Expresso, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, I use Expresso. But that is only to test the regexes. Is there a way to specify the replacement string in the regular expression itself. That will also solve my problem

Comment: If you use Java: str = str.replaceAll(".*fox[A-Z0-9\s]*(.*)dog.*", "$1");    I think it'll work... OUTPUT: str="the big"

Answer (score 0):

Without regexp:

```
    String fox = "The clever fox JUMPED OVER the big dog and ran away.";

    boolean start = false;
    for (String word : fox.split("\\s")) {
        if ("fox".equals(word)) {
            start = true;
            continue;
        }
        if ("dog".equals(word)) {
            break;
        }
        if (start) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need it as a regular expression. I need to feed this into another application which just accepts the exact words that need to be matched. Can you suggest me something using RegEx, please.