# Nested/Repeated Group in Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have to parse a multi line string and retrieve the email addresses in a specific location.

And I have done it using the below code:

```
String input = "Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name=\"winmail.dat\"\r\n"
            + "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n" + "From: ABC aa DDD <aaaa.b@abc.com>\r\n"
            + "To: DDDDD dd <sssss.r@abc.com>\r\n" + "CC: Rrrrr rrede <sssss.rv@abc.com>, Dsssssf V R\r\n"
            + " <dsdsdsds.vr@abc.com>, Psssss A <pssss.a@abc.com>, Logistics\r\n"
            + " <LOGISTICS@abc.com>, Gssss Bsss P <gdfddd.p@abc.com>\r\n"
            + "Subject: RE: [MyApps] (PRO-34604) PR for Additional Monitor allocation [CITS\r\n"
            + " Ticket:258849]\r\n" + "Thread-Topic: [MyApps] (PRO-34604) PR for Additional Monitor allocation\r\n"
            + " [CITS Ticket:258849]\r\n" + "Thread-Index: AQHRXMJHE6KqCFxKBEieNqGhdNy7Pp8XHc0A\r\n"
            + "Date: Mon, 1 Feb 2016 17:56:17 +0530\r\n"
            + "Message-ID: <B7F84439E634A44AB586E3FF2EA0033A29E27E47@JETWINSRVRPS01.abc.com>\r\n"
            + "References: <JA.101.1453963700000@myapps.abc.com>\r\n"
            + " <JA.101.1453963700000.978.1454311765375@myapps.abc.com>\r\n"
            + "In-Reply-To: <JIRA.450101.1453963700000.978.1454311765375@myapps.abc.com>\r\n"
            + "Accept-Language: en-US\r\n" + "Content-Language: en-US\r\n" + "X-MS-Has-Attach:\r\n"
            + "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1\r\n"
            + "X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: <B7F84439E634A44AB586E3FF2EA0033A29E27E47@JETWINSRVRPS01.abc.com>\r\n"
            + "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" + "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: TURWINSRVRPS01.abc.com\r\n"
            + "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal\r\n" + "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 04\r\n"
            + "X-Originating-IP: [1.1.1.7]";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("To:(.*<([^>]*)>).*Message-ID", Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        Pattern innerPattern = Pattern.compile("<([^>]*)>");
        Matcher innerMatcher = innerPattern.matcher(matcher.group(1));
        while (innerMatcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("-->:" + innerMatcher.group(1));
        }
    }
```

Here it works fine. I'm first grouping the part from `To` till the `Message` which is the required part. And then I have another grouping to extract the email ids. 
Is there any better way to do this? Can we do it with one pattern matcher set?

Update:
This is the expected output:

```
-->:sssss.r@abc.com
-->:sssss.rv@abc.com
-->:dsdsdsds.vr@abc.com
-->:pssss.a@abc.com
-->:LOGISTICS@abc.com
-->:gdfddd.p@abc.com
```

Comment: Can you show what you expect to retrieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for all the emails inside `<...>` that come after `To:` and before `Message-ID`. So, you may use a `\G` based regex for one pass:

```
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("(?:\\bTo:|(?!^)\\G).*?<([^>]*)>(?=.*Message-ID)", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = pt.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/2dhluG) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uY7lK7/1)

The regex matches:

- `(?:\\bTo:|(?!^)\\G)` - a leading boundary, either `To:` as a whole word or the location after the previous successful match
- `.*?` - any characters, any number of occurrences up to the first
- `<([^>]*)>` - substring starting with `<` followed with zero or more characters other than `>` (Group 1) and followed with a closing `>`
- `(?=.*Message-ID)` - a positive lookahead that makes sure there is `Message-ID` somewhere ahead of the current match.

Comment: Along with this answer, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35154460/2270563) answer is also helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you could have used lookarounds:

```
(?<=To:.*)<([^>]+)>(?=.*Message-ID)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/NS3eoTXo8tby8Pwe)

---

Unfortunately, [Java doesn't support variable length in lookbehinds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7543781/1225328). A workaround could be:

```
(?<=To:.{0,1000})<([^>]+)>(?=.*Message-ID)
```

Comment: Java supports a [*constrained-witdth lookbehind*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#width) that you show in your answer.